# Travelling outside the USA while on Optional Practical Training (OPT)

Tags: f1-visas

I have a friend who is doing a Science-Technology-Engineering-Mathematics (STEM) optional practical training (OPT). His OPT is ending on 15 June, 2018. His visa is valid till December 2018. He is travelling outside the USA on 21 April, 2018 and coming back on 15 May, 2018. Will there be any issue at immigration while he comes back to the USA, since he is just left with one month of his OPT?

Comment: Why would there possibly be any issue at immigration?

Comment: His OPT is expiring on June 15th, which means he would be out of status. He has to leave the country within 60 days after his OPT expires.  So curious to know if he can travel and can come back without any issue

Comment: For the benefit of others, can you de-abbreviate the un-obvious acronyms (STEM, OPT)?  Some will know them but many will not.  Thank you.

Comment: He won't be out of status in May, will he?  So how does your comment answer @MichaelHampton's?

Comment: On my calendar, May comes before June, and even before December. So I don't understand what the doubt is.

Comment: Basically no, there will not be any issue. Check if the visa allow multiple entry or not

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [F-1 travel FAQ from Homeland Security](https://www.ice.gov/sevis/travel) which mentions:

> If USCIS has approved your OPT you will be expected to have your EAD in hand to re-enter the United States, in addition to your Form I-20, valid passport and visa, and a letter of employment if you have one. If you exceed the limits on unemployment while outside the United States, you will not be eligible to re-enter the United States in F-1 status.

If he has all of these things including proof of a job in the US, he should be able to re-enter for the purpose of finishing his job before his OPT ends. If he doesn't have a job in the US, he might have a harder time explaining his purpose of entry.

Before traveling during OPT, it's always a good idea to check with your Designated School Official to make sure your I-20, SEVIS record, OPT reporting and [STEM OPT reporting requirements](https://studyinthestates.dhs.gov/students-stem-opt-reporting-requirements) are all in order.